# is it possible to detect ssh activity on port 443

Tags: ssh, security, ssl, https

I would like to detect the usage of ssh on port 443 on a linux gateway. 
A kind of counter measure against stuff like sslh.
I think netfilter and iptables would be the solution, but can't find module that fits.

(edit)
At this time it is not a problem for me to prohibe direct connexion to 443 but allow for example a proxy.

So if it is not possible at L7 filtering, is there a proxy solution that permit this filtering.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Is there a way to do layer 7 filtering in Linux?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/465845/is-there-a-way-to-do-layer-7-filtering-in-linux)

Comment: It is possible, but nothing that runs in Linux that I know of. There are heuristics, I recall some software using it - no idea about the false positives -, and advanced hardware traffic shapers using heuristics are also a possibility, but they cost a lot of money.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In general, this isn't possible. For it to be possible, it must be the case that either (1) SSH-over-443 is being done naively rather than actually being tunneled over SSL, or (2) you're breaking all SSL connections and have convinced all clients to accept your fake root CA.